# JanusGraph: Can we use mixed index in with HBase as index backend in Lucene

Tags: lucene, janusgraph

I want to use Lucene as index backend in JanusGraph, Can any one help me how I can do this while storing index into HBase instead of directory path in file system.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot configure JanusGraph with the Lucene indexing backend configured to put indexes in HBase or HDFS.

You can configure JanusGraph with Apache HBase as the storage backend and with Apache Lucene as the indexing backend. Here is an example configuration:

```
graph = JanusGraphFactory.build().
    set("storage.backend", "hbase").
    set("storage.hostname", "127.0.0.1").
    set("storage.hbase.table", "mygraph").
    set("index.search.backend", "lucene").
    set("index.search.directory", "/data/mygraphindex").
    open()
```

Please refer to the JanusGraph documentation for [HBase](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/hbase.html) storage backend and [Lucene](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/lucene.html) indexing backend. Lucene is limited to single-machine deployments and it requires a file system directory. If you need an indexing provider that is distributed, you should consider either [Elasticsearch](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/elasticsearch.html) or [Solr](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/solr.html).

You may also want to read up on the differences between a [composite vs mixed index](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html#_composite_versus_mixed_indexes). If you don't need the additional capabilities of a mixed index (full text, numerical range, or geospatial), then you could use composite indexes only (best for exact matches). Composite indexes are stored in the storage backend and don't require an external indexing backend.

Comment: Thanks Jason, My graph is stored into Hbase as storage backend but my question is how can I store lucene index into Hbase or hdfs?

Comment: It is not possible